# Module registered in App.modules.ts is not available in other modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created one shared module and it registered in `app.module.ts` Whenever I am trying access components from the shared module in another module then registered components not available.

error:

```
'app-custom-autocomplete' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-custom-autocomplete' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-custom-autocomplete' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("                              <div class="input-group">
                                            [ERROR ->]<app-custom-autocomplete (handelItemSelection)="handelItemAction($event)"></app-custom-autocomplete>
"): ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardContainerComponent.html@98:44
```

shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomAutocompleteComponent } from './components/custom-autocomplete/custom-autocomplete.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule 
     ],
    declarations: [
        CustomAutocompleteComponent
    ],
    exports: [
      CustomAutocompleteComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/header/header-component/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './layout/sidebar/sidebar-component/sidebar-component';
import { AppViewComponent } from './views/app-view/app-view-component/app-view.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './shared/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomCellComponent } from './modules/ag-grid/custom-cell/custom-cell.component';
import { CustomcellDropdownComponent } from './modules/ag-grid/custom-cell-render-using-editor/customcell-dropdown/customcell-dropdown.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.mudule';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    AppViewComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

dashboard.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { DashboardContainerComponent } from './dashboard-container/dashboard-container.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomAutocompleteComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/custom-autocomplete/custom-autocomplete.component';
import { EventListComponent } from './event-list/event-list.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardContainerComponent,
    EventListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule ,
    DashboardRoutingModule,

    FormsModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

I am trying to access the component(using selector) from the shared module in the dashboard container component but not able to access it.

Note: If I import sharedModule in the `dashbord.module.ts` module then it working but I want to import it in `App.module.ts`

app.routng :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppViewComponent } from './views/app-view/app-view-component/app-view.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppViewComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.modules#DashboardModule' },
      { path: 'grid', loadChildren: './modules/ag-grid/grid.module#GridModule' }
    ],
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: what is the difference between the dashboard module and the app module?
Why not include the dashboard module in the app module?

Comment: for the lazy loading of the module.

Comment: Try this remove `SharedModule` from `app.module.ts` and add it to `dashboard.module.ts`. Cause you using `app-custom-autocomplete` in dashboard component.

Comment: it's working I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Why you want to import in app.module.ts? You should import where your actual component is registered.

Comment: for multiple modules I have to import a shared module multiple times, instead of that, I try to import in app.module.ts so it will available to all modules. Correct me if i am on the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah but it's will give you above error as you mentioned, Because modules are work ing independently, And your component not registered under app.module.

Comment: Try to import and export `SharedModule` in `app.module.ts`.

Comment: great ! thanks for the explanations.i exportd SharedModule  but not use

Comment: You can use `SharedModule.forRoot()` refer this, https://alligator.io/angular/providers-shared-modules/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dashboard module is a lazy loaded module, it wont be available. You will have to import shared module in dashboard module also.

Answer (score 2):

> If I import sharedModule in the `dashbord.module.ts` module then it
>   working

You just answered your question.

In order to use a component, pipe, directive, etc, inside module A, module A needs to know about it. You either have to declare it inside module A, or export it in module B and then import that module B.

Also you can have shared modules in lazy loaded modules, that won't be a problem.

Comment: what if I want to use some components which are registered in app.module.ts in the another module ?

Comment: It's simple, if a component, pipe, etc, needs to be used in more than one module, then you can declare and export them in a shared module and import the shared module in your other modules.

Comment: for multiple modules I have to import a shared module multiple times, instead of that, I try to import in app.module.ts so it will available to all modules. Correct me if i am on the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You should import `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` from `'@angular/core'` in your `app.module`

Your `App Module` should be like this

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

....

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    exports: [...],
    providers: [
        ...

    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ...
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'; <--------add this ******
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './layout/header/header-component/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './layout/sidebar/sidebar-component/sidebar-component';
import { AppViewComponent } from './views/app-view/app-view-component/app-view.component';
import { BreadcrumbComponent } from './shared/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.component';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomCellComponent } from './modules/ag-grid/custom-cell/custom-cell.component';
import { CustomcellDropdownComponent } from './modules/ag-grid/custom-cell-render-using-editor/customcell-dropdown/customcell-dropdown.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.mudule';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    AppViewComponent,
    BreadcrumbComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]<--------add this ******
})
export class AppModule { }
```